# Linked datepicker fields with values already set

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm using [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to select date ranges. If I have set some value for datepicker's input, `minDate` and `maxDate` don't work correctly for linked datepickers. They are activated only after updating fields manually.

So if I have e.g. value 2015-08-30 00:00 on `#starting` field, the linked field `#ending` must have `minDate` based on starting's value.

I have following settings for Datepicker.

```
$(function () {
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        locale: '<?php echo $lang; ?>',
        minDate: '<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>',
        useCurrent: false
    });

    $("#starting").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#ending').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#ending").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#starting').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put this code on jsfiddle?

Comment: @Sarower, I tried but don't get extension to work in JSFiddle.. Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/5kds8qez/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You selected mindate. but not selected maxdate.
2. Link `bootstrap.min.js` before `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js`. Then it will be work. Please check my demo on jsfiddle

Updated url on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/5kds8qez/2/)